# Difference between 也都不 and 也不都

Tags: grammar, difference

Are they same?

1. 我们也都不是学生 - We also all not are students.
2. 我们也不都是学生  - We also not all are students.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first sentence means `All of us are not students` and the second one `Not all of us are students` (thus some of us may have occupations other than students).

都不是 (all not) is full negation and 不都是 (not all) is partial negation.

Answer (score 2):

@user58955 Not exactly agree with you

**我们也都不是学生** - We also all not are students.

Yes, it means we are all not students, there must be used in this situation:

> A: We are not students.
>
> B: Yes, We also all not are students.

B agree with A and emphasizes the identify of "Students" not others

**我们也不都是学生** - We also not all are students.

These are the different sentences

我们也不都是学生. If you transfer into English, You should say: We are all not only students

it have different meanings in Chinese maybe we are all students, or some of us are students and others are not, or We are not only students but teachers or others maybe.

"We also not all are students" Means "Not all of us are students"

Hope it is clear for you. Boris

Comment: I think this answer is saying that "我们也不都是学生" implies a possibility that 'we' could have multiple occupations, say, we could be students and doctors at the same time. Personally I wouldn't interpret it in this way. I would say 我们也不只是学生 instead of 不都是 in this case.